# How to avoid an extra div in a Backbone Marionette Region or LayoutView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

we are using `Backbone,Marionette and handlebars` for my application. When I try to render my view inside `Marionette.Region`, one extra `div` wrapping around the template. How can I avoid this.

html code :

```
 <div id="mainDiv"></div>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="basic">
        <div id="first"></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
    </script>
```

js code :

```
 //function
var templateCompilation=function(templateId,data){
   var alertCompilation=Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById(templateId).innerHTML);
   return alertCompilation(data);
};

//Application
myApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
myApp.addRegions({
 mainContainer:"#mainDiv"
});
myApp.start();

//first view
var basicView=Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template:function(){
     return templateCompilation("basic",{});
  }
});

//reding view
var basicViewObj=new basicView();
myApp.mainContainer.show(basicViewObj);
```

To avoid extra div, I try with following statements my bad luck nothing working.

```
var basicViewObj=new basicView({el:$("#mainDiv")});
var basicViewObj=new basicView({tagName:""});
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone js: How to remove extra tag in view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663895/backbone-js-how-to-remove-extra-tag-in-view)

Comment: @Evgeniy In my question, I want to refer both `Region` and `view` to the same element. If I am using only `views`, whatever you posted it will help but my question was different. I am using both `Region` and `Views`. I hope you might understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183130/extra-divs-in-itemviews-and-layouts-in-backbone-marionette and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195242/extra-wrappers-in-backbone-and-marionette

Answer (score 1):

#### Important Update:

The code below the line will not work. I wrote it without testing it (was on my mobile). The following update has been tested and incorporated the important comment suggested by `@vzwick`.

As explained below, override `attachHtml` in the Region. We are going to three important changes to `attachHtml` as annotated in the comments below

```
myApp.mainContainer.attachHtml = function (view) {
    // empty the node and append new view
    this.el.innerHTML="";

    // All view elements are attached to that view's el, which acts as a
    // container for that view. The OP wants to get rid of that container 
    // and use the region's el instead. So first get the children of the
    // view that we want to show in the Region
    var children = view.el.childNodes;

    // Now pop each child element into the el of the Region
    // Note that Node.appendChild(Node) removes the first element from the 
    // Node array on each iteration so children[0] will be the next
    // child for each iteration
    while (children.length > 0) {
        this.el.appendChild(children[0]);
    }
     
    // Finally, assign a new el to the view:       
    // view.setElement(element, delegate) is a Backbone method
    // that reassigns the el of the *view* to the parameter *element*
    // and if delegate = true, re attaches the events to the new el
    view.setElement(this.el, true)
}
```

The important thing to note is that the OP's `basicView` now shares its `el` with `myApp.mainContainer`. Since `myApp.mainContainer` is a Region and it does not take an `event` parameter there isn't a chance of there being conflicts if events are re-delegated. The same is true if this is used with a `LayoutView` since the re-delegation of events would happen to the `LayoutView` `Region` `el`, and ***not*** the `LayoutView` `el`, then there should be no conflicts.

---

**Beginning of old post**

I haven't tried this before, but I'm sensitive to your problem from a functional and structural level. What I suggest you do is override the `Region`'s `attachHtml` function.

By default `Backbone.Marionette`'s `attachHtml` is doing this

```
attachHtml: function(view) {
    // empty the node and append new view
    this.el.innerHTML="";
    this.el.appendChild(view.el);
}
```

To change this functionality you could define a new `attachHtml` in your `Region` like the following:

```
attachHtml: function(view) {
    // empty the node and append new view
    this.el.innerHTML="";
    this.el.appendChild(view.el.childNodes);
}
```

Now the `Region` `el` will directly append the inner nodes of the view that you're showing in that region.

To override the original `attachHtml` of the `mainContainer` region you would use your `Application` variable, i.e.

```
myApp.mainContainer.attachHtml = function (view) { ... }
```

with the code example written above.

Comment: This is most likely (cannot verify since I'm on mobile right now) terrible advice since Backbone's View event bindings from the `events` hash are scoped to the view's `el`. Hence, while your hack would have the DOM nodes attached without a container, Backbone's DOM event model would get broken beyond repair.

Comment: Excellent point @vzwick. I have not tested this either, but I wonder if using `this.setElement = MyApp.mainContainer` in the view being `show`n in the `mainContainer` `Region` would fix the problem you bring up. Of course, this would imply that all Backbone events for the `mainContainer` `Region` would have to be wired either on the `Region` or the `View`, since whenever `delegateElements` is called, the first thing it does is `this.undelegateElements()`, and would lead to a lot of confusion about what events are actually wired. But that's what the OP required in the question.