# Backbone/Marionette div wrapper interfering with Select Options

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Layout view, with a region comprising a select input.

```
//template
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <select name="type" id="drop" class="select"></select>
</div>
```

I have a LayoutView which defines the following region and assigns a collection view to populate the select menu with options.

```
//layout
Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    regions: {drop: "#drop"},
    onRender: function() {
        this.getRegion("drop").show(new (Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
            childView: FieldView
        }))(collection: fieldCollection)));
    }
}
```

`FieldView` and `fieldCollection` work fine, but I have  a problem.  When rendering, the collection sub-view wraps the options in a div tag, preventing the select menu from working properly.

```
//Rendered HTML
<select name="type" id="drop" class="select">
    <div>
        <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
        <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
    </div>
</select>
```

Any advice for how to get rid of that pesky div tag?  And shouldn't the subview's `el` be scoped to the select element itself, by virtue of the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since yours is a common enough problem, the extra div functionality is often debated. See, for example, this very interesting [issue](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1976).

Unfortunately, Backbone nor Marionette Views are aware of their parent view, even if that parent view is a LayoutView. In fact, Marionette inherited the wrapper behavior from Backbone, and in the majority of cases its the most common-sense structure for a view to have.

### Change the CollectionView `el`, Live dangerously

You can take the more treacherous route of assigning your Region's element to the CollectionView's `el`, which I described in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473851/2112866). What I suggest there, is to override the Region's `.attachHtml()` method to insert the contents (and not the `el`) of the sub-view directly into the `el` of the Region, ***and***, most importanlty, setting the sub-view's `el` to the Region's `el` using  `view.setElement()`. But read the warnings there carefully. The events between the two views will be *shared!* You can't avoid that.

### Embrace the wrapper, embrace Backbone

Personally, I advocate to work *with*, and not against, Backbone/Marionette on this one. I understand that you may have very good reason to want the `<select/>` element inside your LayoutView. *However*, if you can live without that element in there, I can offer you a very simple and quick fix: You can use whatever (proper) HTML element you want for a view's wrapper. So your `.show()` can look like this:

```
onRender: function() {
  this.getRegion("drop").show(new (Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "select",
    attr: {
      name:"type"
    },
    id: "drop", 
    className: "select",
    childView: FieldView
  }))(collection: fieldCollection)));
}
```

All I did up there was change the vanilla `<div/>` `el` of the view, to

```
<select name="type" id="drop" class="select"></select>
```

Don't forget, you'll want to assign a new element to your Region. Let's the take the original `<div/>` enclosing the `<select/>`, for instance,

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="field-region">

</div>
```

#### Access the `<select/>` element in your LayoutView

The `<select/>` statement is not the `el` of your CollectionView. This may not bother you, but chances are, at some point you'll do something like `$("#drop").val()` in your LayoutView. The good news is that you can natively access `<select/>` since its the `el` of the CollectionView you're passing in. The cost is that you'll want to keep a reference of that view. Something like,

```
onRender: function() {
  this.fieldView = new Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "select",
    attr: {
      name:"type"
    },
    id: "drop", 
    className: "select",
    childView: FieldView
  });
  this.getRegion("drop").show(this.fieldView(collection: fieldCollection));
},

onSelectOption: function () {
  console.log(this.fieldView.$el.val());
}
```